Unity.Properties.SourceGenerator.PropertyBagGenerator cannot be created? Error
Opening a Unity project in Visual Studio 2022 yields the following error:
CS8032: An instance of analyzer Unity.Properties.SourceGenerator.PropertyBagGenerator cannot be created from x:\x\x\2022.3.25f1\Editor\Data\Tools\Unity.SourceGenerators\Unity.Properties.SourceGenerator.dll: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=x' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.. Assembly-CSharp C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.25f1\Editor\Data\Tools\Unity.SourceGenerators\Unity.Properties.SourceGenerator.dll
Does anyone know the root cause of this issue? It only seems to be occuring after updating to Unity 2022.3.25...
Have not tried anything yet as am unsure where to start.

after updating Unity is this in a new empty project or an existing one? If an existing have you tried to delete the Library folder? (it is a cache and will be fully recreated next time you open the project)

.net 6? that doesnt sound right

@derHugo I will try deleting the Library folder now

@BugFinder not quite sure why it is doing this, I have .NET 8 installed on my PC and never chose .NET 6 for the Unity2D project.

You can replace the two files with the files in the Folder with the previous versions, from the previous installation. (Just install the old editor without anything else , and rename the orginal files to keep them safe).
In my case it worked.
